# Elastic Jobs Agent vs Automation Account to run long running Azure SQL stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I see 2 different solutions to deal with long running Azure SQL stored procedures (longer than the 2 minute limitation using Logic Apps): using the Azure Elastic Jobs agent, or using an automation account.

My question is, which solution is recommended? Is there a reason where you would want to use the one over the other?

I've searched for this question but have yet to find any definitive answer.

Comment: As fas as I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview?view=azuresql) Azure Elastic Jobs are in preview. So this is not recommended for production workloads. This is advice I could give you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend you use Azure Automation. To execute a stored procedure with no limit on execution time, just set the timeout setting to zero on the connection. As you can see on below script, you can execute any stored procedure by scheduling a PowerShell runbook on Azure Automation.

```
$DatabaseCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$DatabaseCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$DatabaseCommand.Connection = $DatabaseConnection
# A value of 0 indicates no limit
$DatabaseCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
$DatabaseCommand.CommandText = $SP


Write-Output "EXECUTING QUERY"
# Execute the query
$DatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Create a workflow on Azure Automation that accepts as paramter the Azure SQL server name, the database name, the stored procedure name and the credentials needed to authenticate to the database.